# Updating and passing a value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a bundle creator in Wordpress using Woocommerce, where you select 1 of 4 T-shirts + 1 of 4 pairs of socks and they get added to the cart. Currently I am stuck on figuring out how to approach this. What I currently need to achieve is this:
There is a top image which corresponds to the currently selected product and three smaller images below that. Once you click the small image, it needs to change the top image. There is also a title on the bottom, which corresponds to the currently selected product, that changes together with the top image. [You can see the intended result here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGv7R.png)

I need to somehow get the ID of the product the user clicks on and pass it to other php functions. This is where I got stuck. Can anybody help me out?

The code should look something like this:

```html
<div id="selected-product-image">
  <?php get_the_post_thumbnail(/* ID of the currently selected product*/); ?>
</div>

<ul class="products">
  <?php
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'product_cat' => 't-shirts', 'orderby' => 'name' );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

      <li class="product">

        <div class="select-product"><!--This should have a function to capture the product ID on click. -->
          <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); ?>
        </div>

      </li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <div id="selected-product-name">
        <?php get_the_title(/* ID of the currently selected product*/) ?>;
      </div>

      <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

I understand that I can do something like this using AJAX, but I am not sure how to use the returned ID back in get_the_post_thumbnail() or get_the_title(). This is what I got:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#select-product").click(function() {
      var id = 29; /* Any value for testing */

      jQuery.ajax({
          method: "post",
          url: "/test.php",
          data: {
            productID: id
          }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          alert(data);
          /* How do I use this data to update the picture/title? */
        });
    });
  });
</script>


<!-- THE test.php FILE -->
<?php 
$productID = $_POST['productID'];
echo $productID;
?>
```

UPDATE:
I have tried editing the test.php to echo a function, but I am getting a 500 error every time I try using a Wordpress function inside the test.php file. I tried including the wp-blog-header.php file so the functions can run, but it still doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!-- THE test.php FILE -->
<?php 
include_once('wp-blog-header.php');

$productID = $_POST['productID'];
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($productID);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Pijus, you would need to return the preprocessed value to replace the existing value. In jQuery you can grab the desired element and return the data to it in your success callback.

Comment: So are you suggesting adding something like jQuery(#selected-product-image).html() to the AJAX and just passing a new php line with the ID that I got and doing this for all the divs that need to be updated? How can I exactly output php from this jQuery line?

Comment: you wouldn't pass PHP to the element, the result of the PHP function could be used as the data, you then return that result to the element to update it.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you mean? This would help a lot

Comment: So, the php function get_the_post_thumbnail() evaluates to a result, when called. so your ajax call is going to "test.php", from here you would want to return the result of get_the_post_thumbnail();

Comment: Got it. But is there maybe any other way to just somehow keep updating a variable that I could use in several different php functions? I might need to update 3-4 functions on each click - for it to display the image and title of the corresponding product, as well as to be able to add it to cart. Or should my test.php just return the results of each of the functions?

Comment: Your test.php could return any number of results in an array, then you can point those results wherever you want.

Comment: Gotta try this. Thank you. I hope I can get it to work

Comment: If you get stuck just update your original question with your code so we can see what you have tried

Comment: Please see the updated question in the bottom

Comment: is the function not get_the_post_thumbnail? instead of get_the_thumbnail?

Comment: Made a mistake when updating the post. I am using get_the_post_thumbnail() but it doesn't seem to work